# Vuex/Vue: how to deep watch a mapped state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am importing a mapped state into a component:

```
...mapState('data/story', {
  fullStories: 'stories',
}),
```

this will give `fullStories` the value of the state `stories`, which is an object.

An example would be :

```
this.fullStories = { storyName: "Blah Blah", isActive: false };
```

I am trying to use a `watch` on `isActive`, a property of `fullStories`.  How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with :

```
...mapState('data/story', {
  isActive: (state) => state.fullStories.isActive
})
```

or you can create vuex getter to get a isActive from store object